# Add data to DataTemplatev - XAML/C#

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, datatemplate

I have this code:

```
 <HubSection IsHeaderInteractive="True" x:Uid="Section3Header" Header="My Groups" Padding="40,40,40,32">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView x:Name="List" Grid.Row="6" Margin="40,20,40,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="220" Height="60" Background="#FF729FD4">
                                    <Border Background="#66727272" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="10">
                                        <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Height="32" Width="32" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
```

My question is pretty basic:
I need to create a listview with that code, and in each listview item in need to have a data which I get via websrvice (the type is string).

My question is how canI fill this data  to the DataTemplate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missunderstood something. The datatemplate is used to define the visual appearance of the items of a ItemsControl (e.g. ListView).

In your case the ListView is part of another datatemplate, which is some cases make sense (parent-child display) but I don't think that this is what you want.
So in your case you would need to simply remove the outer datatemplate, and just assign a list of items to the ListView in your code.

If you do need the outer-datetemplate (I'm not familiar with HubSection), then the ListView is part of your datatemplate and you need to bind a property of the type of the datatemplate to your Items collections of the ListView.
Something like:

```
<ListView Items={Binding YourListProperty} ... >
```